# Migrate from npm package `cross-env` to `dotenv`

Tags: node.js, npm, environment-variables, dotenv

I've been reading about the `.env` file and decided to improve my workflow.
Previously, I used `cross-env` to add env-variables right to the npm scripts. example:

```
"server": "babel-node server.js"
"server:prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production babel-node server.js"
```

And along with that, I had a file with global configs and helpers that contains:

```
let configs = {}
configs.env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
configs.devMode = function() {
  if(this.env === 'development') return true
}

// Usage:
const url = configs.devMode() ? 'devUrl' : 'prodUrl'
```

The `dotenv` documentation explained almost all my questions.
I know I can create a `.env` file and pass variables like:

```
HOST=localhost
PORT=3000
```

But, for production, should I write `NODE_ENV` in the same file?
Or is there another way to do it?

The change I'm expecting is having one npm script to run the server on both development and production. But, how is my `.env` file gonna looks like? And also how to improve my `configs` file with the new changes? Should I store the `NODE_ENV` in a variable and default it to `development`? Or `NODE_ENV` will decide the default elsewhere?

Thanks for your help. ^^